# Text not resizing properly with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm almost finished building the portfolio assignment for Free Code Camp but I've hit a bit of a wall.

The page is at - http://codepen.io/jjmax/full/avdVBE/

The only custom code I have for headings is:

```
h1, h2, h3 {
  font-family: 'Ovo', serif;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #a3a3a3;
}

h1 small {
  color: #007ea7;
  font-size: 45%;
}
```

When I resize the screen the h1 heading at the top of the page resizes properly, but the h2 and h3 headings do not. This is most noticeable in the Contact section of the page.

I've tried a few different things but can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use viewport value instead of ems, pxs or pts.

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width
>
> 1vh = 1% of viewport height
>
> 1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
>
> 1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger

Try this `font-size: 4vw;`.
 I have changed font-size only in contact section you can do the same for other section as well.

```
.contact h2 {
    line-height: 3em;
    font-size: 4vw; //changed this
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
```

**[Demo Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvKGeO)**

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that those elements are *supposed* to change size? In `bootstrap.min.css`, the only headings affected by a `@media` breakpoint are `<h1>` elements that are *inside* `.jumbotron` elements (which is the case for the one at the top of your page).

If you want your `<h2>` (or any other elements) to change, you'll have to manually add the `@media` breakpoints to your custom stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (min-width:XXXpx) {
    h2 {font-size: xxx}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd accepted the other answer before I saw this but you've explained it very well, I couldn't find this info anywhere on the Bootstrap site